# How to move files from folder to folder based on name and Basename

Tags: powershell

I am trying to move files that have the same basename from a failed folder to a good folder. The code at the moment is moving the FailedDocs folder to the GoodDocs, but I would only like the files within.

Example files below;

- test.pdf (name)
- test.pdf.xml (basename)

Files to be moved when test.pdf.xml (when basename is used becomes test.pdf) and equals test.pdf within the Good Folder.

```
$sourceFiles = @("C:\Temp\FailedDocs")
$destinationFiles = @("C:\Temp\GoodDocs")

function Perform-File-Move {
    for ($i = 0; $i -lt $sourceFiles.Count; $i++) {
        Get-ChildItem $($sourceFiles[$i]) -Recurse | Where-Object {
            $destinationFiles.Name -eq $sourceFiles.BaseName
        } | ForEach-Object {
            if ($destinationFiles.Name -eq $sourceFiles.BaseName) {
                Move-Item -Path $($sourceFiles[$i]) -Destination
                $($destinationFiles[$i]) -Force
            } else {
                Write-Host "Nothing to Move"
            }
        }
    }
}

Perform-File-Move
```

Comment: I think you need to explain a bit more clearly. When should a file be moved and when not? At the moment all files are being moved because `$destinationFiles.Name` and `$sourceFiles.BaseName` are both `$null` (and therefore equal), I don't think this is your intention

Comment: Is it just PDFs and the corresponding XML files you want to move, or are there other extensions as well?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers - There would be corresponding XML files within this location for the failed items, but also other PDF and XML files that have a different reason for being here.

Comment: So, how do you decide what to move and what not to move then?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers - That's what I am trying to figure out :(  When using BaseName you get the filename without the extension so it matches the name of the destination files where the corresponding PDF is currently held.

Comment: Before writing code that moves data you need to have a clear definition of what you want to move and under which condition you want to move it. That's not really something we could help you with, since we don't know your data.

Comment: It kind of sounds like you want something like `gci $SourceFiles |?{test-Path (join-path $destinationFiles $_.BaseName)}|%{Move-Item $_ -dest (join-path $destinationFiles $_.BaseName)}`, where it will look at the base name for the file, and test to see if there is a folder with that name in the destination folder, and if so it will move the file to that folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thought I would post the answer I came up with for moving the files from the source folder to destination folder based upon basename matching name.

```
$sourceFiles = "C:\Temp\FailedDocs"
$destinationFiles = "C:\Temp\GoodDocs"


function Perform-Compare-And-Move{
   foreach ($XmlFileName in @(Get-ChildItem -Path $sourceFiles)){
   :outer
   foreach ($PdfFileName in @(Get-ChildItem -Path $destinationFiles -Filter *.pdf)){
       if ($XmlFileName.BaseName -eq $PdfFileName) {
       Move-Item  -Path $sourceFiles\$XmlFileName -Destination $destinationFiles -force
       break :outer
       }
       else{}
      }
   }
}

Perform-Compare-And-Move
```